# Public transport from Mataram to Senaru (Tiu Kelep waterfall)

Tags: public-transport, indonesia, lombok

I'm planning travel to Lombok, Indonesia.
I want to go to Sindang Gile waterfall and Tiu Kelep waterfall.
How do I get to Senaru from Mataram by public transport?

Answer (score 2):

There are unfortunately not many options of public transportation in Lombok. I was there recently and decided to rent a motorcycle to drive around the island. There are a couple of places which rent motorcycle for 50-70k IDR/day. If you can't drive or don't have a license, you can rent an *ojek* (motorcycle with driver). The cost depends on how far your destination is. A more comfortable option is to rent a car (around 400-500k/day).

I haven't been in those two waterfalls, but the one closer to Mataram (I think it's called Tiu Gangga). It's a small waterfall, but there's a beautiful smaller waterfall hidden behind that waterfall (a tips from a local man). The road is quite good and easily reachable. I don't know how the road is in Senaru, but expect some adventures ;)